# How To Use Event Listener Inside Selenium Method And Call Method Inside C# Without Repition?

Tags: c#, selenium

I try to listen constantly if a specifc event is triggered, but from what i understand this is not possible using a single or multiple lines of code when using selenium in C#. Instead I have to always use several if statments in between the other selenium operations.

If you know a way to listen if an element is present or not with only a single line or maybe 5, please answer.

For example if I have a code like this:

```
drivers.Navigate().GoToUrl("someurl");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
drivers.Navigate().Refresh();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
drivers.Navigate().GoToUrl("someotherurl");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

How would I keep listening if each site contains a specifc element without using if statements or specific EvenListenerDriver which i would need to put in between the lines? Bec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EventFiringWebDriver` class from `OpenQA.Selenium.Support`

Available events:

```
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> Navigating;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> Navigated;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> NavigatingBack;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> NavigatedBack;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> NavigatingForward;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> NavigatedForward;
public event EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs> ElementClicking;
public event EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs> ElementClicked;
public event EventHandler<WebElementValueEventArgs> ElementValueChanging;
public event EventHandler<WebElementValueEventArgs> ElementValueChanged;
public event EventHandler<FindElementEventArgs> FindingElement;
public event EventHandler<FindElementEventArgs> FindElementCompleted;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverScriptEventArgs> ScriptExecuting;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverScriptEventArgs> ScriptExecuted;
public event EventHandler<WebDriverExceptionEventArgs> ExceptionThrown;
```

And this is an example of how to use it:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events;

const string Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101509/how-to-use-event-listener-inside-selenium-method-and-call-method-inside-c-sharp#75101509";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

var eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

eventDriver.ElementValueChanged += OnElementValueChanged;


eventDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name= 'q']")).SendKeys("selenium");

// Arbitrary delay in order to demonstrate this example.
// In a real app you should use the `WebDriverWait` class.
await Task.Delay(2000);

eventDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name= 'q']")).Clear();
eventDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name= 'q']")).SendKeys("playwright");

void OnElementValueChanged(object? sender, WebElementValueEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
}

// Just to keep active our sample app. In real app 
// you will probably use something else
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did not want.