# How to make selenium chromedriver execute a callback when an element changes? (C#)

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

For example,
a webpage contains the following element:

`<div id="mydiv">abcd</div>`.

After few seconds, the content of the `div` change to any other text, lets say 1234.

I want my C# code to register that and immediately react with some sort of an eventhandler.

At the moment my code is using a `System.Threading.Timer` with a set interval that checks the content inside the element. But, I would like for my code to await these changes, and execute precisely when needed, instead of just mindlessly running until they actually appear

Comment: You can find the element, and then use a WebDriverWait with expected condition of "stalenessOf":  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of how it would look in the code?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75101961/5276946

Answer (score 0):

A quick example here...(untested):

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
   try{
     WebElement myDiv = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='mydiv']"));
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
       // deal with timeout... 
       }
    try{
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(myDiv);
       }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // deal with timeout...might want to check for null before try here
        }
        //now do whatever it is you want to do... 
        //if you need to work with this element, you'll want to grab the reference again
```